# How to use Documet.write to print to browser

Tags: javascript

I am beginner at java script. I am trying to write a script that prompts the users to enter 3 numbers and the program count the number of zero, positive and negative integers user inserted. However,When I output to browser, there is not output shown to browser.
here is my Code

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset= "utf-8">
     <title>Counter</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">

    <!--
        var zero =0;
        var negative =0;
        var positve =0;
        var a1 = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
        var a2 = [];
        var i = 0;

        for( x=0; x< a1.length; x++){
            a2. push (prompt("Enter " + a1[x]+ " integer\n" + ""));
            }
        while (i < a2.length)
        {
            if (a2[i++]== 0)
                zero = zero + 1;
            else if (a2[i++] < 0)
                negative = negative + 1;
            else
                {
                positive = positive + 1;
                i ++;
                }
        }
    //-->

     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <h1> Welcome to Counter System </h1>
     <script>

     <!--
        document.write ("Zeros Numbers entered by the users = " + zero + "      <br/>" +

                                                                           "Positive Numbers entered by the users= " + positive + "<br/> "+
                        "Negative Numbers entered by the users =" + negative +      "<br/>");
                      //-->
               </script>

           </body>
```

Comment: You have a typo when you declared your variable. `var positve =0;` should be `var positive=0;` and it will work. Just note that [`document.write` isn't the best practice for inserting HTML to a document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the values are not getting printed as they are not present in below script tag as script tags get differentiated on run time. You can do like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset= "utf-8">
     <title>Counter</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">

    <!--
        var zero =0;
        var negative =0;
        var positve =0;
        var a1 = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
        var a2 = [];
        var i = 0;

        for( x=0; x< a1.length; x++){
            a2. push (prompt("Enter " + a1[x]+ " integer\n" + ""));
            }
        while (i < a2.length)
        {
            if (a2[i++]== 0)
                zero = zero + 1;
            else if (a2[i++] < 0)
                negative = negative + 1;
            else
                {
                positive = positive + 1;
                i ++;
                }
        }
        
        <!--
        document.write ("Zeros Numbers entered by the users = " + zero + "      <br/>" +

                                                                           "Positive Numbers entered by the users= " + positive + "<br/> "+
                        "Negative Numbers entered by the users =" + negative +      "<br/>");
                      //-->
    //-->

     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <h1> Welcome to Counter System </h1>
```